# passing test.includes into intellij idea test runner parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

for example, in ant i would use something like

fileset dir="src/tests" includes="${test.includes}" excludes="${test.excludes}"/>

in the junit task. there is a Test Runner Parameters field in the Run Configurations in Intellij, but i cant seem to find how to pass that sort of information in.

basic use case: i have abstract tests which have to extend TestCase, but are being run by intellij's test runner (and failing with "no tests found..").

if anyone knows how to do this.. it would be good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid the answer is - this cannot be done this way. Check out the [IntelliJ Jira](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/IDEADEV-30260).